# get request doesn't hit my express route handler

Tags: javascript, express, caching, server-side-rendering

I'm building SSR app with express, and here is my simple render server's entry point

**src/server/server.ts**

```
import * as express from 'express';
import renderer from 'src/server/renderer';
import proxy = require('express-http-proxy');
import createStore from 'src/helpers/createStore';
import config from '@config/index';
import 'express-async-errors';


const app = express();

const port = 3000 || process.env.PORT

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header('Cache-Control', 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
  res.header('Expires', '-1');
  res.header('Pragma', 'no-cache');
  next()
});

app.use('/api', proxy(config.API))

app.set("etag", false)

app.use(express.static('build/client/'))

app.get('*', async (req, res) => {

  console.log(`request headers`, req.headers)
  console.log('req.get.cookie', req.get("cookie"))
  const store = await createStore(req)

  const content = renderer(req, store);

  res.send(content);
})

process.on("unhandledRejection", err => {
  console.log("We have unhandleRejection", err)
})

process.on("uncaughtException", err => {
  console.log("We have uncaughtException", err)
})



app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Render server running on port: ${port}`)
})
```

I Have one get route handler for ('*') every routes, if request hits this router, goes to renderer function and make dynamic html string and return it. here is my renderer function

**src/server/renderer.ts**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import { StaticRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { renderRoutes } from 'react-router-config';
import Routes from '@client/Routes';
import { Request } from 'express';
import { ServerStyleSheet } from 'styled-components';
import { Store } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import * as html from 'build/client/index.html';


export default (req: Request, store: Store) => {

  const tree = (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <StaticRouter location={req.path} context={{}}>
        <div>{renderRoutes(Routes)}</div>
      </StaticRouter>
    </Provider>
  );
  const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();
  renderToString(sheet.collectStyles(tree));
  const styleTags = sheet.getStyleTags();
  console.log(styleTags)

  const content = renderToString(tree);

  return html.replace("$styleTags$", styleTags).replace("$content$", content);

}
```

What its doing is basically find the matching routes components, matching styles and inject into html and return it.
but whenever I request for home route (localhost:3000) , it just don't hit in my route handler function and return html, and bundle.js in my static folder("build/client/) directory for dealing with static assets. I don't 
know the reason but it just don't hit my only route handler !! and I can 
check that out with the fact that it doesn't execute console.log in my route handler's 
first two line and I set the debugger for that too. it doesn't hit and 
return weird contents assumed to be created while ago .

**This is my request and response in browser developer tool(I'm using chrome)**
[image]

I think it has something to do with cache, so I dig on that and disable cache option in browser(set Cache-control header to no-cache I guess) and disable 'etag' on my server and set response to not doing cache. but it's  still same. How can I fix this please?

Comment: Maybe, router handler does not hit because of static middleware (`app.use(express.static('build/client/'))`) which handles all GET requests before your handler.

Comment: Thanks man. problem was I had a index.html on my "build/client/" dir and server serve it right away.